# MySQL Select count based on a select sub query values

Tags: mysql

I have two tables , Table #1 => tbl_notification_flow has the  following information :

```
app_status
Booked
Notified
Missed
Defaulted
```

With the  app_status being the column name and Table #2 => tbl_appointment  has the following information :

```
id  app_status
1   Booked
3   Missed
4   Missed
5   Missed
6   Missed
7   Booked
8   Booked
9   Booked
10  Booked
11  Booked
12  Booked
13  Booked
14  Booked
15  Booked
17  Booked
18  Booked
19  Booked
20  Defaulted
21  Notified
```

With id and app_status being the  columns ,

I want to get a count of all the  app_status based on the  number of times they have appeared on Table #2 ,

I tried the  following query :

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_appointment.id)AS total_count, tbl_appointment.`app_status`
FROM tbl_appointment
WHERE (tbl_appointment.`app_status`) IN
(
SELECT tbl_notification_flow.`notification_type` AS app_status FROM tbl_notification_flow WHERE tbl_notification_flow.notification_type !='Other'
)
```

It gets the following result :

```
total_count app_status
19  Booked
```

Please help with the  best query to get the  right results.

Comment: You are missing a `group by`.

Answer (score 0):

You should aggregate the data by `app_status`.

Here is a reference:

```
SELECT COUNT(tbl_appointment.id)AS total_count,tbl_appointment.`app_status`
FROM tbl_appointment
WHERE (tbl_appointment.`app_status`) IN
(
SELECT tbl_notification_flow.`notification_type` AS app_status 
FROM tbl_notification_flow 
WHERE tbl_notification_flow.notification_type !='Other'
)
GROUP BY tbl_appointment.`app_status`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) to count per notification type and leverage [`LEFT JOIN`](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) to account for situations when there are no events of a particular type in `tbl_appointment` in which case you'd get a `0` instead of an absent row in the result set.

```sql
SELECT n.notification_type app_status, COUNT(a.id) count
  FROM tbl_notification_flow n LEFT JOIN tbl_appointment a
    ON n.notification_type = a.app_status
 WHERE n.notification_type <> 'Other' 
 GROUP BY n.notification_type
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------------+
| app_status | total_count |
+------------+-------------+
| Booked     |          13 |
| Defaulted  |           1 |
| Missed     |           4 |
| Notified   |           1 |
+------------+-------------+
```